# How do I increase the OpenWhisk standalone action runtime memory limit beyond 512MB?

Tags: openwhisk

I'm running OpenWhisk on standalone mode built with Gradle.

The default memory limit is set at 256MB. So when I create actions, I pass the `--memory` parameter like so -

```
./wsk action create bert2 --docker <repository/image:tag> <action-code>.py --memory 1024
```

However, I get back

```
error: Unable to create action 'bert2': requirement failed: memory size 1024 MB exceeds allowed threshold of 512 MB (code Em5QOJg37yCNkUmcb6hTAmK3J8LxwyX7)
Run 'wsk --help' for usage.
```

There are answers for other types of OpenWhisk deployments, but seemingly none for standalone.

In `/core/standalone/src/main/resources/standalone.conf` I see the following values for configurations:

```
  config {
    controller-instances = 1
    limits-actions-sequence-maxLength = 50
    limits-triggers-fires-perMinute = 60
    limits-actions-invokes-perMinute = 60
    limits-actions-invokes-concurrent = 30
  }
```

I'm not able to figure out where the threshold of 512MB is being set.

**UPDATE**

Got it, I was looking in the wrong place, the `application.conf` that holds the config is `<openwhisk-dir>/common/scala/src/main/resources` containing the following lines -

```
    # action memory configuration
    memory {
        min = 128 m
        max = 512 m
        std = 256 m
    }
```

I changed max and std up to 1024 and 512 respectively and my functions are working fine now!